# How to divide a string into 'n' parts in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

For the assignment that I am doing I have to take a string (ex. 'BeeMovie') and divide into two segments based on an integer given as an argument in the function. Following the same example, if I picked an integer of 2, this would mean 'BeeMovie' would be split up as 'BeeM-ovie'. I've tried using the code below, but it splits the string up into two characters each when I would need it to be split into two segments (or however many segments are given by the integer) total.

```
def remix(str, int):
    str1 = str
    x = int
    parts = 0
    i = 0
    parts = [str[i:i+x] for i in range(0, len(str1), x)]
    print(parts)
```

UPDATE:
I was able to use the code below to divide the phrase close to how I wanted, but if the phrase has an odd number of characters it creates another segment, instead of adding the extra characters onto the previous segment. For example: 'BeeMovies' should become 'BeeM-ovies' not 'Beem-ovie-s'. Any thoughts on how to correct this?

```
def remix(str1, x):
    stride = len(str1) / x
    stride1 = int(stride)
    parts = [str1[i:i+stride1] for i in range(0, len(str1), stride1)]
    print(parts)
```

Comment: Don't use `int` as a variable name, it shadows the built-in function.

Comment: Same thing with `str`. Why don't you just define the function `def remix(str1, x):` instead of assigning new variables?

Comment: My bad, I misunderstood the question. Deleted my earlier comment.

Answer (score 2):

Divide the length of the string by `x` to get the length of each slice. Use `ceil()` to round up if it doesn't divide evenly, so you won't get an extra slice.

```
def remix(str1, x):
    stride = ceil(len(str1) / x)
    parts = [str1[i:i+stride] for i in range(0, len(str1), stride)]
    print(parts)
```

There's also no need to assign the variables `i` and `parts` before the list comprehension that overwrites them.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning `from math import ceil`